# Speed up query that uses WHERE id IN

Tags: mysql, sql, database, greatest-n-per-group

Here is a query that takes about 5-6 seconds. The inner part only takes around 50 ms.

```
SELECT id,messages.to,messages.from,message,datetime,messages.read
FROM messages WHERE id IN(   //inside brackets grabs a list of IDs

    SELECT max(messages.id) FROM
        (SELECT id,messages.from FROM messages
        WHERE messages.to = 'username' AND messages.from != 'username'
        UNION
        SELECT id,messages.to FROM messages WHERE
        messages.from = 'username' AND messages.to != 'username')
    AS x
    LEFT JOIN messages ON messages.id = x.id
    GROUP BY x.from)

ORDER BY id DESC
LIMIT 15
```

It's a query that pulls a list of users someone has recently been messaging and also the last message between the two. How can I change this so that it's faster? Maybe without id IN. Maybe multiple queries?

Comment: show your table definitions. Also run `EXPLAIN <your query>` so you can see what indexes each part uses. Show us the output of `EXPLAIN`

Comment: Why are you doing an outer join to messages instead of inner?

Comment: Your narrative says, "list of users someone has recently been messaging" but there is nothing in your query to filter the results to "someone".

Comment: @DanBracuk the 'username' filters it

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Any IN query can be converted to a JOIN.

In this case you need to convert this query from

```
 SELECT * from TABLE where attr IN (SUBQUERY)
```

to

```
  SELECT * from TABLE JOIN (SUBQUERY) AS subTable ON (table.attr = subtable.attr)
```

The main challenge is not to do a "for loop" type of subquery (which is what you have) because for every tuple in the outer query the inner query is executed. If you have a lots of tuples, the result is that you have the innerquery executed A LOT of times.

So think in a way to just do that subquery once. For instance, in this case, make a query that returns for every message id, its maximum id (executed only once) then join to the original messages table.

In other words, don't think for loops. Think in terms of sets that you need to join.

Oh, one more thing I just noticed... what about doing an inner query (select id from messages order by id limit 15) and join this to messages instead of having the LIMIT 15 outside the entire query.

if you have the limit outside, the query will be evaluated FOR EVERY tuple in messages. If you move the LIMIT inside, the DBMS will compute the top 15 before doing the rest of the complex query and it will only do it 15 times!!! rather than for every tuple in the table.
--dmg